# Load CSV file in MySQL DB

Tags: php, sql, csv, import

I'm trying to upload a CSV file in order to update a MySQL table.

I already have done the upload part, but when I try to insert the CSV data into the database, it won't work and won't show any error.

The strange thing to me is that when I try the **exact** same SQL command in the SQL interpreter of phpMyAdmin, the command works and all the lines are insert.

Here is the extract of my code that is suppose to insert the lines on the DB:

```
$name= '/tmp/uploaded/tmp.csv';
$result= move_uploaded_file($_FILES['CSVfile']['tmp_name'], $name);
chmod ($name, 0777);
if (!$result){
    echo "Fail while moving file";
}
else{
    echo "Success";
    //$connect-> query('DELETE from db_name.table_name WHERE 1;');
    $req=$connect->query("LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/uploaded/tmp.csv' INTO TABLE db_name.table_name
    FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\\'
    TERMINATED BY ';'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';"); //<- This command works perfectly on phpMyAdmin SQL interpreter 
    if ($req){
        echo "Success";
    }
    else{
        echo "Fail with the INSERT";
        var_dump($req); //Shows "bool(false)"
    }
}
```

The file contains ~16,000 lines and weight 3.14Mo

Do you have some idea or solution for me please ?

Thanks !

Comment: One reason could be, Lines might not be terminated by `\r\n` once uploaded via http. You can replace all `\r` with `\n` before writing and modify the load command to check only for `\n`

Comment: *it won't work and won't show any error*...do the *Success* messages echo? And are you sure the same exact database you run command in phpMyAdmin is same one you connect in general php?

Comment: Actually, once the CSV file is uploaded on the server, I just move it into the /tmp/uploaded directory but I do not modify it. However, I tried to check only for `\n` and to simply delete the line that check the end of the line but it keep failing...

Comment: The messages that echo are `"Success"` (the first one before the query request), the `"Fail with the INSERT"` and the `var_dump`. I'm 100% sure that it is the exact same database and table (actually I only have access to this database). Plus, when uncomment the `DELETE` query just before, it delete the table contents.

Comment: If your *Fail* message echoes, the query does err out. You need to output the exception message not your custom one. Use a [try/catch](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php) over if/else.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to show up the real error message. I'll try this tomorrow and keep you in touch here.

Comment: So I have the error message and it says `PDO::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1083 [2] => Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual `. I tried to change `TERMINATED BY` by `ENCLOSED BY` but it don't change nothing...

Answer (score 0):

can you not use the 'source' command, then drag and drop?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. What I do to make it work is simply copy/paste the request that is in my PHP code (the one on my post) and put it in phpMyAdmin's interpreter